# Dropping unnecessary text from data using regex and applying it entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

i have table where it has dates in multiple formats. with that it also has some unwanted text which i want to drop so that i could process this date strings

```
Data :

sr.no.           col_1                                col_2
1              'xper may 2022 - nov 2022'          'derh 06/2022 - 07/2022 ubj'
2              'sp@ 2021 - 2022'                   'zpt May 2022 - December 2022'
```

```
Expected Output :

sr.no.           col_1                                col_2
1              'may 2022 - nov 2022'           '06/2022 - 07/2022'
2              '2021 - 2022'                   'May 2022 - December 2022'
```

```
def keep_valid_characters(string):
    return re.sub(r'(?i)\b(jan(uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|jun(e)?|jul(y)?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?)\b|[^a-z0-9/-]', '', string)
```

i am using the above pattern to drop but stuck. any other approach.?

Comment: A monstrous one: `re.search(r'(?i)\b(?:(?:[01]?\d|1[0-2])/\d{4}|(?:(?:jan(?:uary)?|feb(?:ruary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(?:ust)?|sep(?:tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|(?:nov|dec)(?:ember)?)\s*)?\d{4})(?:\s*-\s*(?:(?:[01]?\d|1[0-2])/\d{4}|(?:(?:jan(?:uary)?|feb(?:ruary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(?:ust)?|sep(?:tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|(?:nov|dec)(?:ember)?)\s*)?\d{4}))?\b', string)`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FAcS8U/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to split the pattern construction to multiple strings in complicated case like this:

```py
months = r"jan(?:uary)?|feb(?:ruary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(?:ust)?|sep(?:tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|nov(?:ember)?|dec(?:ember)?"
pat = rf"(?i)((?:{months})?\s*[\d/]+\s*-\s*(?:{months})?\s*[\d/]+)"

df[["col_1", "col_2"]] = df[["col_1", "col_2"]].transform(lambda x: x.str.extract(pat)[0])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   sr.no.                col_1                     col_2
0       1  may 2022 - nov 2022         06/2022 - 07/2022
1       2          2021 - 2022  May 2022 - December 2022
```

Comment: thanks..!!! how to update the above pattern for '(December- March2022)',
 '(July-December 2019)' this type of date format

Comment: @Romi I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'd try to look at it.

Comment: it would be great if you can update. due to duplication of question i am avoiding to open new question. comment would also work